# RegEx for matching digits not followed by specific pattern

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation, regex-greedy

I am trying to build a regex to match the following style of lines:

```
123 warehouse
124 token warehouse.
153token token abc123; etc. - warehouse 
223abdc token abc green warehouse
```

But not these lines:

```
53red warehouse.
323 green token token etc warehouse.
```

The regex I build uses negative lookahead, but testing it on https://regex101.com/ matches all lines:

```
\d+(?!( ?red| ?green)).*(\bwarehouse\b)
```

What is the mistake and how should it be modified? If it matters, the regex should compile under Java (after escaping the necessary characters).

Comment: Can you clarify your requirements? What about the second batch are you trying to avoid? All I can guess is that you want to avoid lines where certain words ("red", "green") appear before "warehouse"? Are those going to be the only three words to consider, or are there more?

Comment: I want to avoid several words (such as red or green) directly after the number. Later in the expression they should be allowed, see the 4th example. There are a couple more fixed words, all possible to be expressed with disjunctions ( ?red| ?green|? blue|? yellow)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern works, if you use a [possessive quantifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) for preventing backtracking:

`\d++` instead of `\d+`

[Here is a demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/56wVvL/1) which is pcre but Java regex should support those as well.

Comment: This is a good solution. Though you can improve the results. +1

Answer (score 2):

With `123red warehouse.`

Your regex matches 1 or more digits `12` then not red or green `3red` then any character `a space` the `warehouse`.

Add a negative lookahead just after the first digits:

```
\d+(?!\d)(?! ?(?:red|green)).*(\bwarehouse\b)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/BU12S7/1)

Comment: why not use a possessive quantifier? In that case there will be no backtracking hence fewer steps to get the result.